# Resubscribing to custom event in C# says event name not in the current context

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, mouseevent

In my WPF project I have a grid of grids that slide over the course of a second. I triggered this by mouseEnter on one of them.
MouseEnter -> OnMouseEnter() -> MoveMicroGrid runs for each grid to move them.
I realized that the MouseEnter event continued to be active for the whole animation, starting it over even if not completed. So I added the SlideCompleted event and am trying to unsubscribe and resubscribe Grid_0_0 from/to it so that nothing can interrupt the animation.

In the Slide Completed method, I am being told "The name 'OnMouseOver' does not exist in the current model". What is causing the issue, and is there a better way to handle putting a pause on 'always active' events?

PS: Left some code out, but included all the parts I thought relevant to the issue. Don't know if that's proper or not for this site...

```
    private void MoveMicroGrid(Grid g, Direction direction) {
        g.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(0, 0);
        Duration duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0));
        DoubleAnimation anim;
        switch (direction) {
            case Direction.Up:
                anim = new DoubleAnimation(-microGridDistanceY, duration);
                anim.Completed += new EventHandler(SlideCompleted);
                g.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, anim);
                break;
            case Direction.Down:
                anim = new DoubleAnimation(microGridDistanceY, duration);
                anim.Completed += new EventHandler(SlideCompleted);
                g.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, anim);
                break;
            case Direction.Left:
                anim = new DoubleAnimation(-microGridDistanceX, duration);
                anim.Completed += new EventHandler(SlideCompleted);
                g.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim);
                break;
            case Direction.Right:
                anim = new DoubleAnimation(microGridDistanceX, duration);
                anim.Completed += new EventHandler(SlideCompleted);
                g.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim);
                break;
        }
        
    }

    private void SlideCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Grid_0_0.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseOver); //<-- This is the error line
        ResetBoardSlide();
    }
    private void OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid_0_0.MouseEnter -= OnMouseEnter;
        SlideBoard(Direction.Down);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've mistyped the name of the event handler. In the `SlideCompleted()` method, you've got this:

```
Grid_0_0.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseOver);
```

But the event handler you've provided in your sample is called `OnMouseEnter`, not `OnMouseOver`. I suspect that's why you're seeing that error message. So you could either rename the method in question, or change the line above to read:

```
Grid_0_0.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseEnter);
```

Comment: ...I uh... It hurts that this is the result to my first question posted here... When the mistake is this stupid are you supposed to delete the original question?... But thank you

Comment: lol, I wouldn't worry about it. Happens to everybody. I was looking at it for probably fifteen minutes before I finally noticed it. This was my first accepted answer, so it's a milestone for both of us. Even still, I don't really know if it's appropriate to delete the question or not. Seems like it wouldn't be particularly helpful outside of these specific circumstances though, so maybe.